# Storing often used immutable data on front-end

Tags: database, mongodb, frontend, bigdata

I am working on a portal where a large chunk of data is the same all the time - let's say it is like a very advanced dictionary with a base of questions to it. Those do not change. I thought that since it is a significant number of docs (total around 20mB) it is not worth downloading it every single time (and for many actions all of it has to be downloaded), but instead, to store it hashed on front-end and access as needed. This would significantly limit server's computation. However, I see that localStorage is limited to 5mB.

My questions is are there any other good solutions/practices to apply in this situation?

Database is mongodb, and it is a MERN stack app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On frontend to use significant payload you can try to use IndexedDB, database located in browser itself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB

Comment: Do you think it makes sense for such a large data set (around 10 000 entries)?

Comment: Depends on your use case and how good is performance on frontend, usually front only shows data, not make that much of processing. In general case I would avoid storing too much on frontend, rather make fast reqeust to backend with most processing done on database side, rather than in node (in case you processing > 1000 items in one go)

Comment: What if I have stuff like dropdown search (have to have those already on the front end to actually search for it), no?

Comment: For dropdown search with too many items to show there special techniques, which allows you to load result on the fly, but in every moment having only visible part of dropdown stored in frontend. Check this link https://medium.com/@leofabrikant/react-autocomplete-with-react-virtualized-to-handle-massive-search-results-7865a8786972